# segmentation fault for an internal C application using decNumber library

Tags: c++, memory, segmentation-fault, memory-address

I am running into a segmentation fault for one of our internal application that uses decNumber. It works like a charm on debian squeeze but seg faults on a wheezy!! Comparing the memory locations here are my findings:

decNumber.h

```
#if   DECDPUN<=2
 #define decNumberUnit uint8_t
#elif DECDPUN<=4
 #define decNumberUnit uint16_t
#else
 #define decNumberUnit uint32_t
#endif
/* The number of units needed is ceil(DECNUMDIGITS/DECDPUN)         */
#define DECNUMUNITS ((DECNUMDIGITS+DECDPUN-1)/DECDPUN)

/* The data structure... */
typedef struct {
int32_t digits;      /* Count of digits in the coefficient; >0    */
int32_t exponent;    /* Unadjusted exponent, unbiased, in         */
                     /* range: -1999999997 through 999999999      */
uint8_t bits;        /* Indicator bits (see above)                */
                     /* Coefficient, from least significant unit  */
decNumberUnit lsu[DECNUMUNITS];
} decNumber;
```

test.cpp

```
decNumber a, b, c;
```

On Squeeze logs show:
&a:0x7fff7dd66880 &b:0x7fff7dd66870 &c:0x7fff7dd66850

On Wheezy logs show:
&a:0x7fff09167078 &b:0x7fff09167084 &c:0x7fff0916709c

The addresses on Squeeze make sense moving from highest to the lowest. Can any one please explain what is happening on the Wheezy machine?

```
// values before the call on Squeeze machine: c.digits = 3 ,   &a:0x7fff7dd66880 &a.exponent:0x7fff7dd66884 &a.bits:0x7fff7dd66888 &a.lsu:0x7fff7dd6688a lsu size=2 . Similarly for b &b:0x7fff7dd66870...
// values before the call on Wheezy machine : c.digits = 3 , &a:0x7fff09167078 &a.exponent:0x7FFF0916707C &a.bits:0x7FFF09167080 &a.lsu:0x7FFF09167082 lsu size=2. Similarly for b &b:0x7fff09167084...
decNumberMultiply(&res, &a, &b, &set);
// value after the call on Squeeze mahcine: c.digits = 3
// value after the call on Wheezy mahcine: c.digits = 721007 -- modified!!!!. Why??
```

Even though the structs are not alligned at 16 byte boundary on the Wheezy, I do not see a overlap of addresses happening across the structs a, b and c. So how is the call to decNumberMultiply modifiying the struct c?

Comment: You need to provide a self-contained test case. Something people can try and test and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Check if the address of `decNumberUnit lsu[DECNUMUNITS]` is aligned to 4 bytes on both platforms. If it's not, then you should add `uint8_t reserved[3]` "above it".

Comment: Thank you for responding barak manos. The size of lsu (and bits field) is 2 bytes on both platforms. However only 12 bytes are being allocated to the struct in Wheezy as opposed to Squeeze which allocates 16 bytes to get to the 4 byte boundary.

Comment: Additional information:
// values before the call on Squeeze machine: c.digits = 3 , &a:0x7fff7dd66880 &a.exponent:0x7fff7dd66884 &a.bits:0x7fff7dd66888 &a.lsu:0x7fff7dd6688a lsu size=2 . Similarly for b &b:0x7fff7dd66870...
// values before the call on Wheezy machine : c.digits = 3 , &a:0x7fff09167078 &a.exponent:0x7FFF0916707C &a.bits:0x7FFF09167080 &a.lsu:0x7FFF09167082 lsu size=2. Similarly for b &b:0x7fff09167084...
decNumberMultiply(&rs, &a, &b, &set);
// value after the call on Squeeze machine: c.digits = 3
// value after the call on Wheezy machine: c.digits = 721007 - modified!!. Why?